# How to properly plot a tree (27k nodes) using a circular tree / leave layout

Tags: graph, tree, networkx, igraph, graphviz

I have this (unbalanced) tree with 27k+ nodes. It is an hierachy. Now I would to plot it as such to obtain a plot something like this (no idea how you would describe it, but I would call it a circular leave tree...?

[image]

However, I am unable to achieve such a result unfortunately. I have already tried `igraph`, `Networkx`, `Maltego`, `Graphviz`, `Gephi`. Hopefully someone can help me / give me tips & tricks or hints.

## Maltego

Gives me quiet easily the following. However I cannot export it to pdf. Furthermore it has this wierd expansion on the top going to the left. I would be able to 'manually' (minimize) move it. However that is not what I would like.

This is btw in my view (with the manual fix) the best result. But I cannot export it to vector or high-res image.

[image]

## igraph

```
import igraph as ig
bigGraphAsTupleList = (('a','b'),('b','c'),('b','d'), ..., ('c','e'))
g = ig.Graph.TupleList(bigGraphAsTupleList)
layout = g.layout("rt_circular") #fr (fruchterman reingold), tree, circle, rt_circular (reingold_tilford_circular)
# bbox = size of picture
ig.plot(g,layout=layout,bbox=(10000,10000),target='mygraph.png')
```

This gives me something like below.

reingold tilford circular
[image]

fruchterman reingold (so much overlap of nodes and connections)
[image]

## Networkx

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(...) #build graph
nx.draw_circular(G) #nx.draw_spring(G) #nx.draw_spectral
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

[image]

## Graphviz (via Networkx)

Also a wierd result a bit similar as the next one Maltego. However

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pydot
from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import graphviz_layout
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(...) #build graph
pos = graphviz_layout(G, prog="circo")
plt.figure(1,figsize=(60,60))
nx.draw(G, pos,node_size=10)
plt.show(block=False)
plt.savefig("Graph.png", format="PNG")
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the dataset?

Comment: @Szabolcs, yes I can, had to obscure it however, here is an .CSV file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mbJL9PT-BP_QkikOjp2v3XGR9_zuno-Y/view?usp=sharing or you can accces via pastebin https://pastebin.com/919cdueK

Comment: The maltego layout looks incredibly good, but I would not be surprised if they just use graphviz under the hood, albeit with a better parameterisation (specifically, a better choice of `root` and/or `mindist`). maltego is clearly using the same or a very similar layout engine to `circo`: for example, in both cases part of the tree is spread out to fill otherwise blank space.

Comment: @Szabolcs if you can help I would very much appreciate it!

Comment: @PaulBrodersen yes indeed, but I cannot export that as a high res picture unfortunately. If will play with the parameters you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my Python solution using the neato layout engine and the
pygraphviz package:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pygraphviz import AGraph

def find_min_root(G):
    deg = {n : len(e) for (n, e) in G.items()}
    worklist = [n for n in deg if deg[n] == 1]
    remain = len(G)
    while remain > 2:
        remain -= len(worklist)
        worklist2 = []
        for n1 in worklist:
            for n2 in G[n1]:
                deg[n2] -= 1
                if deg[n2] == 1:
                    worklist2.append(n2)
        worklist = worklist2
    return worklist

def build_tree(G, n1, visited, tree):
    for n2 in G[n1]:
        if n2 not in visited:
            visited.add(n2)
            tree[n1].add(n2)
            build_tree(G, n2, visited, tree)

def compute_height(T, n1, heights):
    h = heights.get(n1)
    if h is None:
        children = T[n1]
        if not children:
            h = 0
        else:
            h = max([compute_height(T, n2, heights)
                     for n2 in children]) + 1
    heights[n1] = h
    return h

def compute_descendants(T, n1, descendants):
    d = descendants.get(n1)
    if d is None:
        children = T[n1]
        if not children:
            d = 0
        else:
            d = sum([compute_descendants(T, n2, descendants) + 1
                     for n2 in children])
    descendants[n1] = d
    return d

def edge_attrs(n_desc, child_height):
    w = 1
    if child_height == 0:
        pw = 0.25
        if n_desc < 20:
            l = 0.08
            c = '#ffddcc'
        elif n_desc < 40:
            l = 0.15
            c = '#ffddcc'
        elif n_desc < 300:
            l = 0.20
            c = '#ffddcc'
        elif n_desc < 500:
            l = 0.35
            c = '#ffffcc'
        else:
            l = 0.6
            c = '#ddccff'
    elif child_height == 1:
        c = '#77dd55'
        pw = 0.5
        if n_desc < 100:
            l = 0.4
        elif n_desc < 400:
            l = 0.6
        else:
            l = 0.8
    elif child_height == 2:
        c = '#33bb33'
        pw = 0.75
        if n_desc < 1000:
            l = 0.4
        else:
            l = 0.8
    elif child_height == 3:
        c = '#119911'
        if n_desc < 1000:
            l = 0.4
        elif n_desc < 5000:
            l = 0.8
        else:
            l = 3.0
        pw = 1.0
    else:
        c = '#007700'
        if n_desc < 1000:
            l = 0.4
        elif n_desc < 5000:
            l = 0.8
        else:
            l = 3.0
        pw = 1.25
    return c, l, w, pw

def main():
    lines = open('27k.csv').readlines()[1:]
    edges = [l.strip().split(',') for l in lines]

    # Build undirected graph
    G = defaultdict(set)
    for child, parent in edges:
        G[parent].add(child)
        G[child].add(parent)

    # Find best root node
    root = find_min_root(G)[0]
    T = defaultdict(set)
    build_tree(G, root, {root}, T)

    heights = {}
    for n in list(T):
        compute_height(T, n, heights)
    descendants = {}
    for n in T:
        compute_descendants(T, n, descendants)
    G = AGraph(strict = False, directed = False)
    graph_attrs = {
        'dpi' : 300
    }
    G.graph_attr.update(graph_attrs)
    node_attrs = {
        'shape' : 'point',
        'width' : 0.01,
        'color' : '#333333'
    }
    G.node_attr.update(node_attrs)
    for n1, edges in T.items():
        n_desc = descendants[n1]
        for n2 in edges:
            c, l, w, pw = edge_attrs(n_desc, heights[n2])
            G.add_edge(n1, n2, len = l, color = c, weight = w,
                       penwidth = pw)
    G.draw('tree.png', prog = 'neato')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Your data file isn't a tree so I first convert it into a undirected
graph and then I create a well-balanced tree using that graph. Then
all that remains is to set the len attribute on every edge to nudge
neato into creating a good-looking layout.

Colors and pen widths is just to make the output pretty. You can tweak
it by changing the code in `edge_attrs`.

[image]